# Calling async method from non async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await, xamarin.forms

Here is my code in doing so but it seems like I could not do other things once it started calling the async function and then the app will not respond. I would like to just run it to the background.

I'm doing a search and in every 3 letters, it will call the api to get datas if have match. Once I have input 3 letters, it then it calls to the API and I could not input more letters because the app is not responding.

How to call the async function and will just run in the background so that I could still search.

```
void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var newText = e.NewTextValue;
     //once 3 keystroke is visible by 3
     if (newText.Length % 3 == 0)
     {
          //Call the web services
          var result = GettingModel(newText);
          if (result != null || result != string.Empty)
          {
               ModelVIN.Text = result;
          }    
     }
}

private string GettingModel(string vinText)
{
      var task = getModelForVIN(vinText);
      var result = task.Result;    
      return result.Model;
}

private async Task<VINLookUp> getModelForVIN(string vinText)
{
      var deviceId = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Model;
      deviceId = deviceId.Replace(" ", "");
      var requestMgr = new RequestManager(deviceId);

      var VinData = new VINLookUp();    
      VinData = await requestMgr.getModelForVIN(vinText);    
      return VinData;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Just change your event handler to an asynchronouse event handler, ie `async void Entry_TextChanged(){...;var result=await getModelForVIN()...;}'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `GettingModel(string vinText)` method. 
By calling the `Task.Result` you are blocking the main thread.

Calling `.Result` in the UI thread will likely deadlock everything which is what you are experiencing. Use `ContinueWith` or `async void` with `await`.

You can make your `Entry_TextChanged` async and `await` the web request so that it doesn't block the UI.

You can even run it on a separate thread and use `ContinueWith()` if you don't require to make the make user wait for the operation to complete. If you are going that route make sure you use `Device.BeginInvookeOnMainThread()` to run any code that needs to be run on UI thread.

The better code would be :

```
private async void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var newText = e.NewTextValue;
     //once 3 keystroke is visible by 3
     if (newText.Length % 3 == 0)
     {
          //Call the web services
          var result = await GetModelStringForVIN(newText);
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) == false)
          {
               ModelVIN.Text = result;
          }    
     }
} 

private async Task<string> GetModelStringForVIN(string vinText)
{
      var deviceId = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Model;
      deviceId = deviceId.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
      var requestMgr = new RequestManager(deviceId);

      var VinData = await requestMgr.getModelForVIN(vinText);

      return VinData?.Model;
 }
```

The following links would help you understand the concepts better :

1. [Xamarin Async Support Overview](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/)
2. [Asynchronous Operations with Xamarin](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/10/01/asynchronous-operations-with-xamarin.aspx)

Comment: The null check could also be replaced with `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. On the other hand, `ModelVIN.Text` will be null if not initialized. Why not just write `ModelVIN.Text = result` then?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks for the catch, updated the code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - `ModelVIN` is something on a global scope and not a local variable, it might have a value before the execution of the function or not. The OP might want to preserve the previous value if it doesn't meet the condition.

Comment: Careful when using `ContinueWith`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965200/difference-between-await-and-continuewith