# Calling async methods from non-async code

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm in the process of updating a library that has an API surface that was built in .NET 3.5. As a result, all methods are synchronous. I can't change the API (i.e., convert return values to Task) because that would require that all callers change. So I'm left with how to best call async methods in a synchronous way. This is in the context of ASP.NET 4, ASP.NET Core, and .NET/.NET Core console applications.

I may not have been clear enough - the situation is that I have existing code that is not async aware, and I want to use new libraries such as System.Net.Http and the AWS SDK that support only async methods. So I need to bridge the gap, and be able to have code that can be called synchronously but then can call async methods elsewhere.

I've done a lot of reading, and there are a number of times this has been asked and answered.

[Calling async method from non async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865307/calling-async-method-from-non-async-method)

[Synchronously waiting for an async operation, and why does Wait() freeze the program here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485115/synchronously-waiting-for-an-async-operation-and-why-does-wait-freeze-the-pro)

[Calling an async method from a synchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010337/calling-an-async-method-from-a-synchronous-method)

[How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

[Calling async method synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously)

[How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

The problem is that most of the answers are different! The most common approach I've seen is use .Result, but this can deadlock. I've tried all the following, and they work, but I'm not sure which is the best approach to avoid deadlocks, have good performance, and plays nicely with the runtime (in terms of honoring task schedulers, task creation options, etc). Is there a definitive answer? What is the best approach?

```
private static T taskSyncRunner<T>(Func<Task<T>> task)
    {
        T result;
        // approach 1
        result = Task.Run(async () => await task()).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // approach 2
        result = Task.Run(task).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // approach 3
        result = task().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // approach 4
        result = Task.Run(task).Result;

        // approach 5
        result = Task.Run(task).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


        // approach 6
        var t = task();
        t.RunSynchronously();
        result = t.Result;

        // approach 7
        var t1 = task();
        Task.WaitAll(t1);
        result = t1.Result;

        // approach 8?

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The answer is you don't do it. You add new methods that are asyncronous and keep the old synchronous ones there for the legacy callers.

Comment: That seems a little harsh, and really kills the ability to use new code. For example, the new version of the AWS SDK doesn't have non-async methods. Same for a number of other third party libraries. So unless you rewrite the world, you can't use any of these?

Comment: Option 8: Maybe the [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) could be an option ?

Comment: Result property only causes deadlocks when called while Task is still running. I'm not 100% sure but you should be safe if you properly wait until the task ends, as in approach 7.

Comment: Showing sample of why you can't use synchronous API from asynchronous code could help finding better answer than on by @scott

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it's the other way around - trying to use asynchronous code from synchronous

Comment: I understand what your exact question is  about, but you've mentioned that you need to use some other SDK which does not support async - so I thought that you concerning to make your code async and still use synchronous SDK... If that SDK requires synchronous callbacks where you want to use async code that is indeed a problem... and there is no good solution - just pick whatever issues you are ok to leave with.

Comment: I may not have been clear enough - I'll update the question as well, but I want to use a SDK that only supports async (e.g., the AWS SDK). The code that I am working on sits between an existing code base that is all synchronous and the AWS SDK. The existing code base needs to call my code, which will use the AWS SDK. So the problem is how to bridge (synchronous) calls to my code to async methods in the SDK.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

> So I'm left with how to best call async methods in a synchronous way.

First, this is an OK thing to do. I'm stating this because it is common on Stack Overflow to point this out as a deed of the devil as a blanket statement without regard for the concrete case.

It is not required to be async all the way *for correctness*. Blocking on something async to make it sync has a performance cost that might matter or might be totally irrelevant. It depends on the concrete case.

Deadlocks come from two threads trying to enter the same single-threaded synchronization context at the same time. Any technique that avoids this reliably avoids deadlocks caused by blocking.

In your code snippet, all calls to `.ConfigureAwait(false)` are pointless because the return value is not awaited. `ConfigureAwait` returns a struct that, when awaited, exhibits the behavior that you requested. If that struct is simply dropped, it does nothing.

`RunSynchronously` is invalid to use because not all tasks can be processed that way. This method is meant for CPU-based tasks, and it can fail to work under certain circumstances.

`.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is different from `Result/Wait()` in that it mimics the `await` exception propagation behavior. You need to decide if you want that or not. (So research what that behavior is; no need to repeat it here.) If your task contains a single exception then the `await` error behavior is usually convenient and has little downside. If there are multiple exceptions, for example from a failed `Parallel` loop where multiple tasks failed, then `await` will drop all exceptions but the first one. That makes debugging harder.

All these approaches have similar performance. They will allocate an OS event one way or another and block on it. That's the expensive part. The other machinery is rather cheap compared to that. I don't know which approach is absolutely cheapest.

In case an exception is being thrown, that is going to be the most expensive part. On .NET 5, exceptions are processed at a rate of at most 200,000 per second on a fast CPU. Deep stacks are slower, and the task machinery tends to rethrow exceptions multiplying their cost. There are ways of blocking on a task without the exception being rethrown, for example `task.ContinueWith(_ => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).Wait();`.

I personally like the `Task.Run(() => DoSomethingAsync()).Wait();` pattern because it avoids deadlocks categorically, it is simple and it does not hide some exceptions that `GetResult()` might hide. But you can use `GetResult()` as well with this.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You could also write it as `Task.Run(async () => await DoSomethingAsync())`, but does that really matter since there's only 1 line of code anyway? Code inside `DoSomethingAsync()` can still use `await` anyway if it needs to, right?

Comment: @void.pointer semantically, those are equivalent except that `await` will drop all but the first exception. Otherwise, you can use the style that you like. I can see arguments for both styles. What `DoSomethingAsync` does internally is shielded from the outside. It can use any mechanism it likes to produce a `Task`. `await` does that, but so does `Task.FromResult` and others.

Answer (score 59):

> I'm in the process of updating a library that has an API surface that was built in .NET 3.5. As a result, all methods are synchronous. I can't change the API (i.e., convert return values to Task) because that would require that all callers change. So I'm left with how to best call async methods in a synchronous way.

There is no universal "best" way to perform the sync-over-async anti-pattern. Only a variety of hacks that each have their own drawbacks.

What I recommend is that you keep the old synchronous APIs and then introduce asynchronous APIs alongside them. You can do this using the ["boolean argument hack" as described in my MSDN article on Brownfield Async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

First, a brief explanation of the problems with each approach in your example:

1. `ConfigureAwait` only makes sense when there is an `await`; otherwise, it does nothing.
2. `Result` will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`; if you must block, use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead.
3. `Task.Run` will execute its code on a thread pool thread (obviously). This is fine **only if** the code *can* run on a thread pool thread.
4. `RunSynchronously` is an advanced API used in extremely rare situations when doing dynamic task-based parallelism. You're not in that scenario at all.
5. `Task.WaitAll` with a single task is the same as just `Wait()`.
6. `async () => await x` is just a less-efficient way of saying `() => x`.
7. Blocking on a task started from the current thread [can cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Here's the breakdown:

```
// Problems (1), (3), (6)
result = Task.Run(async () => await task()).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// Problems (1), (3)
result = Task.Run(task).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// Problems (1), (7)
result = task().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// Problems (2), (3)
result = Task.Run(task).Result;

// Problems (3)
result = Task.Run(task).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// Problems (2), (4)
var t = task();
t.RunSynchronously();
result = t.Result;

// Problems (2), (5)
var t1 = task();
Task.WaitAll(t1);
result = t1.Result;
```

Instead of any of these approaches, since you have *existing, working synchronous code*, you should use it alongside the newer naturally-asynchronous code. For example, if your existing code used `WebClient`:

```
public string Get()
{
  using (var client = new WebClient())
    return client.DownloadString(...);
}
```

and you want to add an async API, then I would do it like this:

```
private async Task<string> GetCoreAsync(bool sync)
{
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    return sync ?
        client.DownloadString(...) :
        await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(...);
  }
}

public string Get() => GetCoreAsync(sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

public Task<string> GetAsync() => GetCoreAsync(sync: false);
```

or, if you *must* use `HttpClient` for some reason:

```
private string GetCoreSync()
{
  using (var client = new WebClient())
    return client.DownloadString(...);
}

private static HttpClient HttpClient { get; } = ...;

private async Task<string> GetCoreAsync(bool sync)
{
  return sync ?
      GetCoreSync() :
      await HttpClient.GetString(...);
}

public string Get() => GetCoreAsync(sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

public Task<string> GetAsync() => GetCoreAsync(sync: false);
```

With this approach, your logic would go into the `Core` methods, which may be run synchronously or asynchronously (as determined by the `sync` parameter). If `sync` is `true`, then the core methods *must* return an already-completed task. For implemenation, use synchronous APIs to run synchronously, and use asynchronous APIs to run asynchronously.

Eventually, I recommend deprecating the synchronous APIs.

Comment: Can you explain more the item six?

Comment: @EmersonSoares: As I explain in my [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), you can `await` the result of a method because it returns `Task`, not because it's `async`. This means that [for trivial methods, you can drop the keywords](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: I faced recently with same problem in asp.net mvc 5 + EF6. I used TaskFactory as this answer suggests https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097498/1683040, and it did the trick for me :), but not sure for other scenarios.

Comment: I understand your proposal using `WebClient`. But what benefit does the Core method has when using `HttpClient`? Wouldn't it be cleaner and more efficient if the synchronous method directly calls the the `GetCoreSync` method, leaving the boolean argument hack out in this case?

Comment: @Creepin: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @StephenCleary, just to be clear: In your own Nito.AsyncEx library's `WaitAndUnwrapException()` you simply call `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, without wrapping it in `Task.Run()`. Unless anything significant change recently, I guess it means that it is prone to deadlocks? Is there any context where you *don't* see that risk? WCF? ASP.Net Web API? Console? Windows Service? Other?

Comment: @tsemer: Yes, `WaitAndUnwrapException` is prone to deadlocks just the same as `Wait` is. It is literally a `Wait` but avoids the `AggregateException` wrapper. This is dangerous, so it's deliberately in a separate namespace so devs have to "opt in" to seeing it at all. Any contextless environment will not cause deadlocks, including Console, Win32 services, thread pool threads, and [ASP.NET Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html). But just because you *can* block doesn't mean you *should* - you would lose all the benefits of `async` code.

Comment: @StephenCleary: We just demonstrated contextless deadlocks today due to thread pool exhaustion.

Comment: Minor nit about an otherwise good answer: The `CoreAsync(bool sync)` pattern seems clumsy to me. Why not, instead, define an interface, and make two implementations of that interface - a sync one and an async one? Or have client code directly call either the sync or async version of a method?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: The `CoreAsync` pattern is an implementation detail; that method is `private` and is not directly called by anything. The only thing that pattern does is eliminate the (almost) duplication that would otherwise exist between the sync and async implementations. The client code would call the sync/async version, or use sync/async interfaces; but both the sync and async versions are just wrappers around the (private) `CoreAsync` implementation detail.

Comment: Almost 7 years later, this answer is incredibly informative.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I just went thru this very thing with the AWS S3 SDK. Used to be sync, and I built a bunch of code on that, but now it's async. And that's fine: they changed it, nothing to be gained by moaning about it, move on.
So I need to update my app, and my options are to either refactor a large part of my app to be async, or to "hack" the S3 async API to behave like sync.
I'll eventually get around to the larger async refactoring - there are many benefits - but for today I have bigger fish to fry so I chose to fake the sync.
Original sync code was 
`ListObjectsResponse response = api.ListObjects(request);` 
and a really simple async equivalent *that works for me* is 
`Task<ListObjectsV2Response> task = api.ListObjectsV2Async(rq2);`
`ListObjectsV2Response rsp2 = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
While I get it that purists might pillory me for this, the reality is that this is just one of many pressing issues and I have finite time so I need to make tradeoffs. Perfect? No. Works? Yes.

Answer (score -5):

You Can Call Async Method From non-async method .Check below Code .

```
     public ActionResult Test()
     {
        TestClass result = Task.Run(async () => await GetNumbers()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return PartialView(result);
     }

    public async Task<TestClass> GetNumbers()
    {
        TestClass obj = new TestClass();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await APICallHelper.GetData(Functions.API_Call_Url.GetCommonNumbers);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(result);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```