# How to deal with UWP async when Android and iOS are not async?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

My Xamarin.Forms app has several interfaces (for `Dependency`s) with implementations for Android and iOS. The methods in them are not async. Now I want to add the implementations for these interfaces for UWP, but several of the needed methods are async so they don't fit the signatures. How do I deal with this? Is the only solution to create a separate interface for UWP?

Comment: could you post the code for your interface?  Hard to offer suggestions when there is no code.

Comment: Something like `string Method1();` which would need to be in UWP: `Task<string> Method1();`.

Comment: Can you do async interface for all 3 platforms?

Comment: @YuriS Thanks. That's what deckertron_9000 wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these scenarios I tend to use the Task.FromResult method for the non-async implementations. Example: you have a method on Windows that returns a Task of type bool and you want to implement the same functionality on Android and iOS for methods that return bool.

```
public interface ISample
{
    public Task<bool> GetABool();
}
```

On Windows you would just return the Task

```
public class WindowsSample : ISample
{
    public Task<bool> GetABool()
    {
        // whatever implementation
        return SomeTaskOfTypeBool(); 
    }
}
```

On Android or iOS you would wrap the value in a Task

```
public class AndroidSample : ISample
{
    public Task<bool> GetABool()
    {
        // replace with however you get the value.
        var ret = true;
        return Task.FromResult(ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice idea. Instead of trying to sync the async, let's async the sync. If you can't beat them, join them. :)

Comment: Every time I see someone calling .Result on a Task, a little piece of me dies.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the await keyword. You have to create a new Task and wait for the Task to finish. A separate interface is not necessary. Exception handling with Tasks can be tricky, inform yourself.

Calling an async method Method1 with return value:

`string s = Task.Run(() => Method1()).Result;`

Without return value:

`Task.Run(() => Method1()).Wait;`

.Rest or .Wait block until the Task is completed.

More Details:
[Calling async methods from non-async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324300/calling-async-methods-from-non-async-code)

Comment: You've just opened a bag of deadlocks.