# Calling an async method without await in a non-async method?

Tags: .net, async-await

What is the behavior of calling an async method without the await and in a non-async method? I'm asking because I see Visual Studio not displaying any warning on the call to the async method as if it were a perfectly normal thing to do. Does the async method behave as if it were synchronous in such case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously), [Calling async method synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087), [Calling async methods from non-async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324300).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not uncommon for async methods to be called in this fire-and-forget fashion (and yes, the usual advice regarding not using/being extra careful with `async void` also fully applies in this case).

Calling an async method from a method which does *not* have the `async` modifier does *not* result in the async method executing synchronously.

Instead, the async method will execute up to the first `await` on an awaitable having `IsCompleted == false` (i.e. first awaited instance of `Task` which does not complete synchronously). At that point the calling (outer) method will resume execution, and the rest of the async method will be scheduled to run at a later point.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that a method has `async` as a modifier is an implementation detail of the method. It just means you can write asynchronous code more easily. It doesn't change how the method is *called* at all.

Typically an async method returns `Task` or `Task<T>`. It can return `void`, but that's usually only used for event handlers, as otherwise the caller can't tell when the method has completed. In C# 7 it can also return a custom task type.

Now how the caller *uses* that return value is up to them. Suppose a method returns `Task<int>` - a synchronous method might call that method then ignore the returned task completely ("fire and forget"), or attach a continuation with `ContinueWith`, or pass it to an async method that *will* await it. None of that changes how the async method itself behaves.