# AWS SDK: Equivalent S3FileInfo methods for .net standard

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk

I'm working on upgrading our software to target .NET Standard.  I note that the AWS SDK does not support the AWS.S3.IO library, and therefore the `S3FileInfo` code we used previously needs to be updated.

One that jumps out is the `Length` and `Exists` methods.  These used to do a HEAD request to S3 to determine what was required.  I can't see an equivalent right now - and it looks as though I'll have to do a `GetObjectRequest` instead, which is a full GET request.

Is this correct, or is there a way to perform a HEAD operation to check for existence and length in the .NET Standard AWS SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks as though GetObjectMetadataAsync is the best alternative.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetObjectMetadataAsyncStringStringCancellationToken.html

Comment: Link appears broken.

Comment: I've fixed the link

Comment: Any other alternatives available?

Answer (score 2):

This [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245007) post led me to the original code for `S3FileInfo`:

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/_bcl/IO/S3FileInfo.cs)

I find that extremely useful for recreating the functionality in .Net Core 6 that I require, namely, does the file exist or not.

Here's what my code ended up being, based on that code:

```
public async Task<bool> fileExists(string bucket, string key)
{
    try
    {
      // you provide the s3Client in your call, or create a new one
      await s3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(bucket, key);

      return true;
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
    {
       if (string.Equals(ex.ErrorCode, "NotFound"))
           return false;

       throw;
     }
}
```

(yes, `GetObjectMetadataAsync` throws an exception if the key doesn't exist; reminds me of my Microsoft DAO days!)

Maybe someday Amazon will have a better SDK for .Net Core?

*** UPDATE Aug 2023 ***

A little over a year later, not much has changed.  However these links may be helpful to future readers:

[Requesting a way to check for existence without an exception](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/2584)

[dlchambers example of how to call synchronously if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324300/calling-async-methods-from-non-async-code)  Beware of deadlocks!