# How can I turn a synchronous structure to asynchronous on ASP.NET CORE

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, task

I have tree layer of classes to get data from database and serve it within an Action. I get data from database old way, using `SqlParameter` classes.

I need to/want to reconstruct this methods to asynchronous methods. What truly I want is to learn how to make these synchronous methods to Asynchronous. And make them work different threads and use them across entire app.

What I don't want to do is to Use Ado.Net or using ready methods like `HttpClient.GetAsync`

I read this question: [Calling async methods from non-async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324300/calling-async-methods-from-non-async-code) but couldn't apply to my structure and couldn't be sure if it is work properly, avoids deadlocks.

My old structure is like that:

My Action in My `BlockController`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new BlockDb().Select());
}
```

The `Select` Method in `BlockDb` class:

```
    public List<Block> Select()
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = DbJobs.ExecuteReader("BlockSelect");
            List<Block> list = new List<Block>();
            Block cs;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cs = new Block();
                cs.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
                cs.Name= Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);
                cs.Dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Dt"]);
                cs.Ok = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Ok"]);
                list.Add(cs);
            }

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            return list;
        }
```

And the last one `ExecuteReader` Method in `DbJobs` **static** class:

```
    public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string ProcName, params SqlParameter[] prmtr)
    {
        SqlDataReader Result = null;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(cnn);
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ProcName, connect);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (SqlParameter item in prmtr)
                command.Parameters.Add(item);

            if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connect.Open();

            Result = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            //connect.Close();
            //connect.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }

        return Result;
    }
```

I can't be sure bu the result of an Action could be like that:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await new BlockDb().SelectAsync());
}
```

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert code to async, it's best to start at the lowest level and work your way up. So, starting with `DbJobs`, change every method to its asynchronous equivalent and `await` the result:

```
public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string ProcName, params SqlParameter[] prmtr)
{
  SqlDataReader Result = null;
  SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(cnn);
  try
  {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ProcName, connect);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    foreach (SqlParameter item in prmtr)
      command.Parameters.Add(item);

    if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      await connect.OpenAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    Result = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
  }
  catch { }

  return Result;
}
```

This will give you a compiler error telling you to change your `DbJobs.ExecuteReader` signature. So, if you do what the compiler error tells you to do, you'll end up with:

```
public static async Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(string ProcName, params SqlParameter[] prmtr)
```

Now you'll get compiler errors for all the old code that called `DbJobs.ExecuteReader`, e.g., `BlockDb.Select`. So, change those to use asynchronous methods, too:

```
public List<Block> Select()
{
  SqlDataReader dr = await DbJobs.ExecuteReaderAsync("BlockSelect");
  List<Block> list = new List<Block>();
  Block cs;
  while (await dr.ReadAsync(CancellationToken.None))
  {
    cs = new Block();
    cs.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
    cs.Name= Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);
    cs.Dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Dt"]);
    cs.Ok = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Ok"]);
    list.Add(cs);
  }

  dr.Close();
  dr.Dispose();
  return list;
}
```

Again, you'll get a compiler error telling you how to change `BlockDb.Select`:

```
public async Task<List<Block>> SelectAsync()
```

And finally, you'll do the same for `Index`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  return View(await new BlockDb().SelectAsync());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know it was too easy like that. Or it became easier after this awesome explanation of yours. There were hundereds of error like you said. It was a quite challange to fix them all. But Visual Studio didn't  tell me to change signature. It didn't even make a propese. I don't want to use Async suffix anyway.

Comment: @Ebleme: If it's too much to change all at once, you can have both synchronous and asynchronous APIs together (temporarily) by using the [bool argument hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the article. This is what I need, really. I am going to read it.