# Why the SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync is not working? It jumps to "return currentToken.AccessToken" before GetAccesTokenAsync call it's finished

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronization, semaphore

`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` is not working. It jumps to `return currentToken.AccessToken` before the `GetAccesTokenAsync` call it's finished and throws NullException. I tried to use also AsyncLock, AsyncSemaphore and some other methods I read online but it seems like nothing it's working in my case.

```cs
public static class HttpClientHelper
{
    #region members
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private static Token currentToken;
    #endregion

    public static string GetAuthorizeToken(ref HttpClient client, string username, string password)
    {
        GetToken(client, username, password);

        return currentToken.AccessToken;
    }

    private static async void GetToken(HttpClient client, string username, string password)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            if (currentToken == null)
            {
                await GetAccesTokenAsync(client, username, password);
            }
            else if (currentToken.IsExpired)
            {
                await GetAccessTokenByRefreshToken(client);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    private static async Task<Token> GetAccesTokenAsync(HttpClient client, string username, string password)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> requestBody = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        requestBody.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", username));
        requestBody.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", password));
        requestBody.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));

        try
        {
            using (var urlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestBody))
            {
                var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(client.BaseAddress + "/api/authentication/token"), urlEncodedContent);
                currentToken = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<Token>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() });
            }

            return currentToken;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logers.Log.Error($"Error while getting the access token {e}");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `GetToken` in a [fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46053175/11683) way.

Comment: Your `GetToken()` is a void async method which means that you can't `await` it - and it will return immediately when it hits the first `await` in it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson There is no other solution than making GetAuthorizeToken async too and call GetToken with await?

Comment: There is a solution if you want to call an async method from somewhere where you can't await it (in other words, changing an async call into a normal synchronous call) - do you want me to post an example as an answer?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, please. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: @Catleen Is there a reason why you cant make `GetAuthorizeToken` async? That is by far the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is to change your `private static async void GetToken()` method declaration to return a Task: `private static async Task GetToken()`. If it doesn't return a Task, you won't be able to wait for it to complete. ("async void" is "fire-and-forget" as mentioned by GSerg.)

The most basic way to call an async method from a sync method is to use `Task.Run(...).Wait()`, as shown below.

Pay attention to the call to `Task.Run(waitForSem).Wait();` which is what actually turns the async call into a sync call.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(() => timeWaitForSem(1), () => timeWaitForSem(2));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void timeWaitForSem(int id)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {id} is waiting for semaphore.");
            Task.Run(waitForSem).Wait(); // <=== HERE is the important bit.
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {id} finished waiting for semaphore after {sw.Elapsed}.");
        }

        static async Task waitForSem()
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            // Keep hold of the semaphore for a while.
            await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false); 
            _semaphore.Release();
        }

        static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    }
}
```

The output of this program will be something like:

```
Thread 1 is waiting for semaphore.
Thread 2 is waiting for semaphore.
Thread 1 finished waiting for semaphore after 00:00:02.0133882.
Thread 2 finished waiting for semaphore after 00:00:04.0316629.
```

What you must NOT do is to simply put `waitForSem().Wait();` rather than `Task.Run(waitForSem).Wait();`, because you are likely to get a deadlock that way (particularly if it's called from an application with a message pump, such as WinForms).

For more information, see [Calling async methods from non-async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324300/calling-async-methods-from-non-async-code)

An alternative and slightly more efficient approach is to use [JoinableTaskFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.joinabletaskfactory?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll`. To use that, you'd need to reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll` or add it via NuGet.

This has the advantage of not starting a new thread if it does not need to. If you use `JoinableTaskFactory`, the code would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(() => timeWaitForSem(1), () => timeWaitForSem(2));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void timeWaitForSem(int id)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {id} is waiting for semaphore.");

            _jtf.Run(async () => await waitForSem().ConfigureAwait(false));

            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {id} finished waiting for semaphore after {sw.Elapsed}.");
        }

        static async Task waitForSem()
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            // Keep hold of the semaphore for a while.
            await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            _semaphore.Release();
        }

        static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        static readonly JoinableTaskFactory _jtf = new JoinableTaskFactory(new JoinableTaskContext());
    }
}
```