# Async in Task ContinueWith behavior?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

How could you explain the following behaviour:

```
await Task.Run(() => { }).ContinueWith(async prev =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Continue with 1 start");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Continue with 1 end");
}).ContinueWith(prev =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Continue with 2 start");
});
```

Why will we get “Continue with 2 start” before “Continue with 1 end”?

Comment: ContinueWith doesn't work with `async/await` nor does it know about them. `await` is a *replacement* for `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith` instead of `await`?

Comment: You might be better off doing without `ContinueWith` and just use `await`.  _["await leads to much simpler code. Additionally, as noted by Servy in comments, awaiting a task will "unwrap" aggregate exceptions which usually leads to simpler error handling"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18965299/585968)_

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But, how to explain that behavior? Why await returns task for anonymous method. It's just an investigation.

Comment: Because you don't await your first continuation. Thus your first continuation is started, prints "Continue with 1 start", calls Task.Delay, schedules the remaining code (printing "Continue with 1 end") as another implicit continuation, returns, which kicks off continuation 2. Your implicit continuation is then triggered after Task.Delay ends = after one second.

Comment: Because you created an `async void` method that is never awaited by anything

Comment: @ckuri the continuation *is* awaited. What it does though, is fire off a task that nobody is going to await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below is equivalent to your example, with variables explicitly declared, so that it's easier to see what's going on:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => { });

Task<Task> continuation1 = task.ContinueWith(async prev =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Continue with 1 start");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Continue with 1 end");
});

Task continuation2 = continuation1.ContinueWith(prev =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Continue with 2 start");
});

await continuation2;
Console.WriteLine($"task.IsCompleted: {task.IsCompleted}");
Console.WriteLine($"continuation1.IsCompleted: {continuation1.IsCompleted}");
Console.WriteLine($"continuation2.IsCompleted: {continuation2.IsCompleted}");

Console.WriteLine($"continuation1.Unwrap().IsCompleted:" +
    $" {continuation1.Unwrap().IsCompleted}");

await await continuation1;
```

Output:

> Continue with 1 start
>   Continue with 2 start
>   task.IsCompleted: True
>   continuation1.IsCompleted: True
>   continuation2.IsCompleted: True
>   continuation1.Unwrap().IsCompleted: False
>   Continue with 1 end

The tricky part is the variable `continuation1`, that is of type `Task<Task>`. The [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method does not unwrap automatically the `Task<Task>` return values like [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) does, so you end up with these nested tasks-of-tasks. The outer `Task`'s job is just to create the inner `Task`. When the inner `Task` has been created (not completed!), then the outer `Task` has been completed. This is why the `continuation2` is completed before the inner `Task` of the `continuation1`.

There is a built-in extension method [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) that makes it easy to unwrap a `Task<Task>`. An unwrapped `Task` is completed when both the outer and the inner tasks are completed. An alternative way to unwrap a `Task<Task>` is to use the `await` operator twice: `await await`.

Answer (score 4):

`ContinueWith` doesn't know anything about `async` and `await`. It *doesn't* expect a `Task` result so doesn't await anything even if it gets one.  `await` was created as a *replacement* for `ContinueWith`.

The cause of the problem is that `ContinueWith(async prev =>` [creates an implicit async void delegate](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#implicit-async-void-delegates). `ContinueWith` has no overload that expects a `Task` result, so the only valid delegate that can be created for `ContinueWith(async prev =>`  question's code is :

```
async void (prev) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(“Continue with 1 start”);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(“Continue with 1 end”);
}
```

`async void` methods can't be awaited. Once `await Task.Delay()` is encountered, the continuation completes, the delegate yields and the continuation completes. If the application exits, `Continue with 1 end` may never get printed. If the application is still around after 1 second, execution will continue.

If the code after the delay tries to access any objects already disposed though, an exception will be thrown.

If you check `prev.Result`'s type, you'll see it's a `System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult`. `ContinueWith` just took the `Task` generated by the async/await state machine and passed it to the next continuation