# Task<T> Exit Event

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Why does `Task<T>` not have a `OnExit` event that is invoked upon exiting through Exception or finishing regularly.
If I have an operation, for which I dont know when it will finish and whose result my continuing code does not depend on, I wont want to await it.
If im interested in the result however, whenever it may occur, I would have to await `Task<T>`.

Am I missing something here and such behaviour is already natively possible?

Naive delegate type of `OnExit` in my head would be something like this
`delegate void TaskExitHandler<T>(T result, Exception exception)`.

Comment: You can just use [`.ContinueWith()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-5.0) for these purposes. By the way, if you don't await a task somewhere (or use a ContinueWith to check it) you will not see exceptions in the thread, so errors could go unnoticed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Awesome, I didnt know about that. I'll look into it, thank you!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981091/1997232).

Comment: Please note _[Difference between await and ContinueWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965200/difference-between-await-and-continuewith)_ particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18982576/585968) answer

Comment: As a side note, the name `OnExit` does not communicate failure. A better name would probably be `OnError`: `public static void OnError(this Task task, Action<Exception> handler) { _ = task.ContinueWith(t => handler(t.Exception), default, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default); }`

Comment: Or... you can just use `await` to do *the same exact thing*.