# Sequential await VS Continuation await

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await

I was wondering what is the best/correct way of writing asynchronous code that is composed of two (or more) async and dependent (the first have to finish to execute second) operations.

Example with async/await:

```
await RunFirstOperationAsync();
await RunSecondOperationAsync();
```

Example with Continuation:

```
await RunFirstOperationAsync()
    .ContinueWith(t => RunSecondOperationAsync());
```

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767218/is-async-await-keyword-equivalent-to-a-continuewith-lambda) SO discussion

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'd want to use `await` if you possibly can.

`ContinueWith` has a number of issues. I describe this briefly in my blog post on [why `ContinueWith` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), which builds on my earlier blog post on [why `StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (they share many of the same issues).

In particular:

- `ContinueWith` does not have a good default `TaskScheduler`. The default task scheduler is `TaskScheduler.Current` (not `TaskScheduler.Default`), and resuming on the current `SynchronizationContext` must be done by hand if desired.
- `ContinueWith` has non-ideal default [options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). For asynchronous code, you would want `DenyChildAttach` and `ExecuteSynchronously`, at least.
- `ContinueWith` does not understand asynchronous continuations, which generally requires an additional `Unwrap` call to work around this limitation.
- `ContinueWith` treats its `CancellationToken` argument in a surprising way. More on that [in this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) of mine.

These arguments are all summarized on my [blog post on Task continuations](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html). `await` does not have any of these drawbacks.