# Running tasks in sequence inside an infinite loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I have a several tasks that are run in sequence; one after the other.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork1())
            .ContinueWith((t1) => DoWork2())
            .ContinueWith(t2 => DoWork3());
```

I want to put this inside a loop so they run indefinitely (After `DoWork3()` is done, go back to `DoWork1()`. I tried putting inside a while loop, but the loop goes to the next iteration as soon the task is launched, creating a boatload of new tasks.

Would also be nice to have a way to exit condition to break out of the loop, maybe pass a cancellation token.

Thanks!

Comment: Great!  Let us know how you go

Comment: Ended up following @MickyD advise on using successive awaits and replaced the ContinueWith's. Either one works, but awaits seems to more readable / flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use async/await:

```
async void DoStuff()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork1())
            .ContinueWith((t1) => DoWork2())
            .ContinueWith(t2 => DoWork3());
    }
}
```

Or you can call the method again after the last task is completed, simulating a `while(true)` :

```
void DoStuff()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork1())
        .ContinueWith((t1) => DoWork2())
        .ContinueWith(t2 => DoWork3())
        .ContinueWith(t3=> DoStuff());
}
```

You could also `Wait` for the task explicitly, but this will block the thread you are executing on:

```
void DoStuff()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork1())
            .ContinueWith((t1) => DoWork2())
            .ContinueWith(t2 => DoWork3())
            .Wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the task to complete before starting the next iteration of while loop.

```
while(true) 
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork1())
            .ContinueWith((t1) => DoWork2())
            .ContinueWith(t2 => DoWork3());
    task.Wait(); 
}
```

Without `task.Wait()` (or a similar mechanism) the tasks will be scheduled to run, but the next iteration of while loop will begin without waiting for these tasks to complete.

Comment: Though nice, in this day and age successive inline `await`s are kinder to kittens than `.ContinueWith()`

Comment: @MickyD how would you write the above using inline awaits? I'd like to know!

Comment: `await Task.Run(() => DoWork());  await Task.Run(() => DoWork2());  await Task.Run(() => DoWork());`   Not hard.  Also [check out the dangers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36798058/585968) of `ContinueWith`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as follows:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //your loop
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork1()).ContinueWith((t1) => DoWork2()).ContinueWith(t2 => DoWork3());
    tasks.Add(task);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```