# Do multiple awaits to the same Task from a single thread resume in FIFO order?

Tags: c#

Supposing a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) is created and `await`ed multiple times from a single thread.  Is the resume order FIFO?

#### Simplistic example: *Is the `Debug.Assert()` really an invariant?*

```c#
Task _longRunningTask;

async void ButtonStartSomething_Click()
{
    // Wait for any previous runs to complete before starting the next
    if (_longRunningTask != null) await _longRunningTask;

    // Check our invariant
    Debug.Assert(_longRunningTask == null, "This assumes awaits resume in FIFO order");

    // Initialize
    _longRunningTask = Task.Delay(10000);

    // Yield and wait for completion
    await _longRunningTask;

    // Clean up
    _longRunningTask = null;
}
```

*`Initialize`* and *`Clean up`* are kept to a bare minimum for the sake of simplicity, but the general idea is that the previous *`Clean up`* *MUST be complete* before the next *`Initialize`* runs.

Comment: If it isn't single thread, it is definitely not completed/resumed in FIFO order, but since the question is on single thread.... do you try it out?

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that requires FIFO completion notifications. I would make `_longRunningTask` be the `Task.Delay(10000)` followed by a continuation that nulls out the `_longRunningTask`. That way, you are guaranteed that awaiting the `_longRunningTask` will not complete until the variable is nulled out.

Comment: Even if you test and get reliable FIFO continuations 100% of the time in your WinForms or WPF app, this is an unreasonable risk to take. What if someone takes your code and integrates it into a lib that can run in a console app or ASP.NET? What if they notice that your async chain includes a long-running blocking operation and wrap the whole thing in `Task.Run`? You're introducing a lot of brittleness just to save yourself a simple `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()/Release()` combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no, it's not guaranteed.

Furthermore, [you should *not* use `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html); among other problems, it has a confusing default scheduler (more details on my blog). You should use `await` instead:

```
private async void ButtonStartSomething_Click()
{
  // Wait for any previous runs to complete before starting the next
  if (_longRunningTask != null) await _longRunningTask;
  _longRunningTask = LongRunningTaskAsync();
  await _longRunningTask;
}

private async Task LongRunningTaskAsync()
{
  // Initialize
  await Task.Delay(10000);

  // Clean up
  _longRunningTask = null;
}
```

Note that this could still have "interesting" semantics if the button can be clicked many times while the tasks are still running.

The standard way to prevent the multiple-execution problem for UI applications is to *disable the button*:

```
private async void ButtonStartSomething_Click()
{
  ButtonStartSomething.Enabled = false;
  await LongRunningTaskAsync();
  ButtonStartSomething.Enabled = true;
}

private async Task LongRunningTaskAsync()
{
  // Initialize
  await Task.Delay(10000);
  // Clean up
}
```

This forces your *users* into a one-operation-at-a-time queue.

Comment: Also, if splitting up a function is unsightly (e.g. if there're lots of variables to bring across), an alternative is using anonymous functions: `_longRunningTask = ((Func<Task>)(async () => { await Task.Delay(10); }))();`

Answer (score 2):

The order of execution is pre-defined, however there is potential race condition on `_longRunningTask` variable if ButtonStartSomething_Click() is called concurrently from more than one thread (not likely the case).

Alternatively, you can explicitly schedule tasks using a queue. As a bonus a work can be scheduled from non-async methods, too:

```
void ButtonStartSomething_Click()
{

        _scheduler.Add(async() =>
        {
              // Do something
              await Task.Delay(10000);
              // Do something else
        });
}

Scheduler _scheduler;  




class Scheduler
{
    public Scheduler()
    {
        _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Func<Task>>();
        _state = STATE_IDLE;
    }


    public void Add(Func<Task> func) 
    {
       _queue.Enqueue(func);
       ScheduleIfNeeded();
    }

    public Task Completion
    {
        get
        {
            var t = _messageLoopTask;
            if (t != null)
            {
                return t;
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
            }
        }
    }

    void ScheduleIfNeeded()
    {

        if (_queue.IsEmpty) 
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _state, STATE_RUNNING, STATE_IDLE) == STATE_IDLE)
        {
            _messageLoopTask = Task.Run(new Func<Task>(RunMessageLoop));
        }
    }

    async Task RunMessageLoop()
    {
        Func<Task> item;

        while (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
        {
            await item();
        }

        var oldState = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _state, STATE_IDLE);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(oldState == STATE_RUNNING);

        if (!_queue.IsEmpty)
        {
            ScheduleIfNeeded();
        }
    }


    volatile Task _messageLoopTask; 
    ConcurrentQueue<Func<Task>> _queue;
    static int _state;
    const int STATE_IDLE = 0;
    const int STATE_RUNNING = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer under [`Task.ContinueWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321576(v=vs.110).aspx).  It appear to be: **no**

Presuming *[`await` is just `Task.ContinueWith()` under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767218/is-async-await-keyword-equivalent-to-a-continuewith-lambda)*, there's documentation for [`TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) that reads:

> **A hint** to a TaskScheduler to schedule task in the order in which they were scheduled, so that tasks scheduled sooner are **more likely to run sooner**, and tasks scheduled later are more likely to run later.

<sup>(bold-facing added)</sup>

This suggests there's no guarantee of any sorts, inherent or otherwise.

## Correct ways to do this

For the sake of someone like me (OP), here's a look at the more correct ways to do this.

Based on Stephen Cleary's answer:

```
private async void ButtonStartSomething_Click()
{
    // Wait for any previous runs to complete before starting the next
    if (_longRunningTask != null) await _longRunningTask;

    // Initialize
    _longRunningTask = ((Func<Task>)(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);

        // Clean up
        _longRunningTask = null;
    }))();

    // Yield and wait for completion
    await _longRunningTask;
}
```

Suggested by Raymond Chen's comment:

```
private async void ButtonStartSomething_Click()
{
    // Wait for any previous runs to complete before starting the next
    if (_longRunningTask != null) await _longRunningTask;

    // Initialize
    _longRunningTask = Task.Delay(10000)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            // Clean up
            _longRunningTask = null;

        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    // Yield and wait for completion
    await _longRunningTask;
}
```

Suggested by Kirill Shlenskiy's comment:

```
readonly SemaphoreSlim _taskSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

async void ButtonStartSomething_Click()
{
    // Wait for any previous runs to complete before starting the next
    await _taskSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        // Do some initialization here

        // Yield and wait for completion
        await Task.Delay(10000);

        // Do any clean up here
    }
    finally
    {
        _taskSemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

<sup>(Please -1 or comment if I've messed something up in either.)</sup>

## Handling exceptions

Using continuations made me realize one thing: `await`ing at multiple places gets complicated really quickly if `_longRunningTask` can throw exceptions.

If I'm going to use continuations, it looks like I need to top it off by handling all exceptions within the continuation as well.

i.e.

```
_longRunningTask = Task.Delay(10000)
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        // Clean up
        _longRunningTask = null;

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        // Consume or handle exceptions here

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

// Yield and wait for completion
await _longRunningTask;
```

If I use a `SemaphoreSlim`, I can do the same thing in the `try-catch`, and have the added option of bubbling exceptions directly out of `ButtonStartSomething_Click`.