# Callback with async and await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-6.0

I have questions regarding the execution order of async jobs.

I will ask my question with example because it is easier to be understandable.

It is an official example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx with some twist.

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    //async operation:
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
    DoWork1();

    // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync.
    string urlContents = await getStringTask;

    DoWork2();

    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Can I say `DoWork2` is a callback of `client.GetStringAsync`?

If so, `DoWork2` is not immediately executed following the completion of `client.GetStringAsync` IF `DoWork1` runs longer time than `client.GetStringAsync`.

Am I right here?

Comment: Yes you start the task, when `DoWork1()` is completed, you will await the task. If it's already been completed, `DoWork2` starts immediately. If not, `DoWork2` starts when the task finished.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Then it is NOT the kind of "callback" I expected. In my opinion, a callback should be immediately executed once its async function is done.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want DoWork2 to execute (on completion of getStringTask) even if DoWork1 hasn't finished yet? Maybe look into the [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) method.

Comment: And that's why this isn't generally referred to as a "callback". It's related, and under the covers may make use of a callback, but you won't generally find `await` described as a callback.

Comment: @HansKesting  Yes, I want `DoWork2` to be executed immediately upon the complition of getStringTask.  It seems "await" and "Task.ContinueWith" functions the same. See this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767218/is-async-await-keyword-equivalent-to-a-continuewith-lambda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `DoWork2` is not immediately executed following the completion of
>   `client.GetStringAsync` if `DoWork1` runs longer time than
>   `client.GetStringAsync`

Once you hit that point `await client.GetStrinkAsync`, `DoWork1()` has already completed, as from your example it looks as it's execution is synchronous. Once `client.GetStringAsync` completes, then `DoWork2` is set to execute.

The execution flow will be:

1. `GetStringAsync` asynchronously starts. It is executed until it hits it's first internal `await`, and then yields control back to `AccessTheWebAsync`.
2. `DoWork1()` kicks off. As it's synchronous, everyone waits for it's completion
3. `client.GetStringAsync` is *asynchronously waited* for completion. `await` will naturally yield the control of execution to it's caller.
4. Once `client.GetStringAsync` completes, execution will return to `AccessTheWebAsync` and `DoWork2()` will execute synchronously.
5. `urlContents.length` will be returned.

Generally, everything after the first `await` keyword is set to be the continuation for the rest of the method.

Comment: Is there a way to make the `DoWork2` immediately executed once `client.GetStringAsync` is finished?

Comment: @derek But that is exactly what happens. Once `client.GetStringAsync` completes, `DoWork2` will execute.

Comment: Saying `DoWork1()` takes 10 seconds to finish while `client.GetStringAsync` takes 5 seconds. So when `client.GetStringAsync` finishes, `DoWork1()`  is still running so we need wait for `DoWork1()`  to complete, right? Then 5 seconds later, `DoWork1()` finishes. Only at this time, `DoWork2()` can start to work. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @derek No. `DoWork1()` is **synchronous**. Nothing will run until it completes. If `GetStringAsync` takes 5 seconds, then once the method finishes `DoWork1`, `GetStringAsync` will already be completed and execution will synchronously continue to `DoWork2`.

Comment: Isn't `GetStringAsync` running with `DoWork1()` at the same time in different threads for the first 5 seconds?

Comment: @derek Yes, you're correct, I forgot that `GetStringAsync` is executed without being awaited. We'll have to wait for `DoWork1` to complete before the `await GetStringAsync`  hits.

Answer (score 5):

[Yuval's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39286248/263693) is correct.

To answer your followup question:

> Is there a way to make the DoWork2 immediately executed once client.GetStringAsync is finished?

Possibly. It depends on the context of this code. It's not possible to have `DoWork1` and `DoWork2` both running on the UI thread at the same time (obviously, a single thread can only do one thing at a time). But if this is called from a thread pool context, then sure, it's possible to run them both simultaneously.

However, you should shift your thinking from "callback" to "operation". That is, don't think of it as `DoWork2` being a "callback" of `GetStringAsync`. Instead, think of it like this: I have an operation `GetStringAsync`, and I have an operation `DoWork2`; I need a new operation that does one and then the other.

Once you shift your thinking this way, the solution is to write a method for the new operation:

```
async Task<string> GetStringAndDoWork2Async()
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
  DoWork2();
  return result;
}
```

Now you can use that new operation in your higher-level method:

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
  var task = GetStringAndDoWork2Async();

  DoWork1();

  string urlContents = await task;

  return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In:

```
//async operation:
Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
```

you are creating a Task that runs an asynchronous operation and returns immediately to the caller, next `DoWork1()` execute synchronously, once done `string urlContents = await getStringTask;` suspends the continuation of the method until the awaited task has completed; once completed the program continues with `DoWork2()`.

Comment: Saying `getStringTask` blocks is exactly the opposite of what happens when you properly `await` an async method.

Comment: Agreed: 'suspend' or 'suspend the execution'  or assign the remaining of AccessTheWebAsync() as a continuation of 'getStringTask' is a more correct usage. Block is incorrect (updated)

Comment: No, the task does run immediately. All that `await` does is take a Task (or other awaitable) that some other piece of code has already started and it either does nothing (if the task is already complete) or pauses execution of the current method until the task is complete. But, just to re-emphasise, `await` doesn't **start** anything.