# Parameterized action

Tags: c#, delegates, task-parallel-library

I accidentally bumped into an issue, that I was able to resolve. However, I am a worried about my inability to understand why the error-ed code was able to compile (at first place).

Following is the error-ed code, that compiles fine:

```
Task<string> myTask = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return "mystrineg";
            });
            myTask.ContinueWith(t => action, CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

The issue with the above code is : `action` won't get called at all.
Here is the fix I made:

```
Task<string> myTask = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return "mystrineg";
            });
            myTask.ContinueWith(t => action(t.Result), CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

My question is, why is the compiler allowing to call a parametrized action without an argument?

Comment: All the answers are right. However, I had to choose the one that arrived early and was clear. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why is the compiler allowing to call a parametrized action without an argument?

It does not. In your first version, you did not call `action` at all. Not even with no arguments. You would have needed to pass it directly without the lambda or call it with an empty pair of `()` to actually call it.

While `action;` would not be a valid statement, `.ContinueWith` will not only take an `Action<Task>`, but also a `Func<Task, T>` and that is exactly what you passed... a function taking a Task, returning whatever Type your `action` has: `t => action;`

Answer (score 3):

Your first code will use this [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784422(v=vs.110).aspx), and what it will do is to return the action delegate and will not execute it at all.

The overload you actually need is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174(v=vs.110).aspx) and your second code actually uses it and will execute your action.
I am wondering why didn't you use [async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) instead of [ContinueWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767218/is-async-await-keyword-equivalent-to-a-continuewith-lambda) and [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Task.Factory.StartNew which can be [dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Your code can be much simpler:

```
Task<string> myTask = Task.Run(() =>
                      {
                          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                          return "mystrineg";
                      });
string str = await myTask;
action(str);
```

Comment: Very valid point. However, the code is old and there is no way to use .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

```
t => action
```

is a short for:

```
t => { return action; }
```

hence the result.