# Now that we have an "await" keyword, is there any benefit to using ContinueWith method?

Tags: c#

Picture the following code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("www.someaddress.yo");
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Is there any added benefit, other than possibly saving a single thread, by writing the above code the following way:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 string content = await client.GetAsync("www.someaddress.yo")
       .ContinueWith(r => r.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe performance-wise both codes end up doing the same amount of work.

Comment: @JohnB could you add some more insight as to why that is?

Comment: its not just a code smell, it can cause blocking to happen.

Comment: await asynchronously unwraps the result of your task, whereas just using Result would block until the task had completed

Comment: Here is an excellent article explains it well https://montemagno.com/c-sharp-developers-stop-calling-dot-result/

Comment: @JohnB The canonical source is https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Async await keyword equivalent to a ContinueWith lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8767218/11683)

Comment: @GSerg - nice - noted :-)

Comment: @JohnB I'm confused - doesn't ContinueWith reflect itself once the task has completed execution, such as Result would no longer pose danger for blocking?

Comment: Just dropping a very good talk about async/ await and correcting common mistakes with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0mcYVxJEl0

Comment: I thought `ContinueWith` was a chaining technique - the `Result` bad boy is still going to do his blocking move

Comment: article on the diff between `continuewith` and `await` here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/difference-between-await-and-continuewith-keyword-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: @SpiritBob you're right in that `r.Result` won't block, but the `.Result` at the end of the last line is still going to block.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm guessing there's no avoiding it? Thank you all for the valuable reads!

Comment: "saving a single thread" - I see no threads. Nothing in your first sample is going to create threads. Since it's not been linked yet that I can see - [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not sure to the technicalities, but I believe a task is composed of workers called threads? I've edited my response above with the "possible" keyword and I read somewhere that using ContinueWith would pass the thread in the previous task to do the new task, effectively (possibly) saving a thread?

Comment: @SpiritBob no, a task is just a promise that *something* will complete in the future. That something  *may* get executed on a threadpool thread, or not. A task returned by a TaskCompletionSource for example doesn't run on any threads.  In any case, `now` was back in 2012 when `async/await` were introduced. Classes like HttpClient are *meant* to be used with `async/await`. In fact, using `ContinueWith` like this can allocate objects without providing any benefit. It sure makes expection handling harder though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second snippet has no benefits, doesn't "save" any threads while allocating another task object and making debugging and exception handling harder by wrapping any exceptions in an AggregateException.

A task is a *promise* that something will produce some output in the *future*. That something may be :

- A background operation running on a threadpool thread
- A network/IO operation that *doesn't* run on any thread, waiting instead for the Network/IO driver to signal that the IO has finished.
- A timer that signals a task after an interval. No kind of execution here.
- A TaskCompletionSource that gets signalled after some time. No execution here either

`HttpClient.GetAsync`, `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` or `Content.ReadAsStringAsync` are such IO operations.

`await` doesn't make anything run asynchronously. It only *awaits* already executing tasks to complete without blocking.

Nothing is gained by using `ContinueWith` the way the second snippet does. This code simply allocates another task to wrap the task returned by `ReadAsStringAsync`. `.Result` returns the original task.

Should that method fail though, `.Result` will throw an `AggregateException` containing the original exception - or is it an AggregateException containing an AggregateException containing the original? I don't want to find out. Might as well have used `Unwrap()`. Finally, everything is still awaited.

The only difference is that the first snippet returns in the original synchronization context after each await. In a desktop application, that would be the UI. In many cases you *want* that - this allows you to update the UI with the response without any kind of marshalling. You can just write

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("www.someaddress.yo");
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
textBox1.Text=content;
```

In other cases you may not want that, eg a library writer doesn't want the library to affect the client application. That's where `ConfigureAwait(false)` comes in :

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("www.someaddress.yo").ConfigureAwait(false);
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```